# i want each email to be unique for a certain field's id . how is it possible for validation in laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation

### laravel 5

In laravel 5 form validation I need email to be only unique for a certain field's id in the db table.

```
$this->validate($request,[
        'name'=>'required',
        'email' => 'unique:users,email,',
        'password'=>'required',
        ]);
```

Comment: please define `certain field's id` ?

Comment: which means consider i have a table called users in it fileds id , name , email ,company_id . company_id is a foreign key from company table so i want email to be entered unique in the table only by considering company_id   for example if company_id 1 , another company_id 2. so it is possible to add email to the table if the company_id is different only else not

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way:

```
$companyId = $request->get('company_id'); // selected company
$this->validate($request,[
    'name' => 'required',
    'email' => [
        'required',
        "unique:users,email,NULL,id,company_id,$companyId"
    ],
    'password'=>'required',
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ignore a specific id in the database, you can use `ignore`. For example, when a user is updating his profile, we want to allow him to send his email address, it should not be considered `a not unique`.

Here is the [docs details](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-unique). And here is your code updated to match that:

```
    $this->validate($request,[
        'name'=>'required',
        'email' => [
            \Illuminate\Validation\Rule::unique('users', 'email')->ignore($user->id),
        ],
        'password'=>'required',
    ]);
```

However, if want to ignore more than `one` id or want to customize the query, you need to add a `where` clause:

```
    $this->validate($request,[
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => [
            'required',
            \Illuminate\Validation\Rule::unique('users')->where(function ($query) {
                // Add any constraints you want for the query here.
                return $query->whereNotIn('id', [1, 2, 3, 4]);
            }),
        ],
        'password'=>'required',
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Third` and `Fourth` param to ignore for `company_id`

```
    $company_id = 1;// Company will be here
```

And in validation

```
    'email' => 'unique:users,email,'.$company_id.',company_id',
```